# dealing with oauth_required in cached pages

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api, webapp2

I am developing a web application based on Google App Engine (Python/webapp2).
Since the app uses several Google APIs i have decorated the @DECORATOR.oauth_required get/post method of the app RequestHandlers.

Everything works fine except when I stop using the site for a while and, when coming back to it, I start noticing the APIs stopped working. I think this is due to the fact the authorization expired but the Login form is not depicted because the browser is using the cached version of that page. I think so because if I force the reload (shift+reload) the Login form suddenly appears.

What should I do to avoid this?

Comment: Can you please post any relevant info from the console and/or network tab in the chrome dev tools when this issue occurs for you? I'm trying to figure out where the issue is coming from. If possible, could you create a git repository of a basic and simple app that demonstrates the issue, perhaps by taking your current code, copying it, and cutting out anything non-essential?

Answer (score 2):

You can instruct the browswer not to cache your page by sending the correct HTTP headers back :

```
resp.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
resp.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
resp.headers["Expires"] = "0"
```

Comment: But I want the browser to cache pages

Comment: Everything linked from within your page will still be cached, like images, scripts and css,if you follow this approach. But obviously you do not want to cache the base HTML without verifying the user is logged in.